# Where can I find a better manual for learning Blender than blender.org

Tags: interface

I can do Maya because I learned where everything I need is located. However with Blender nothing.

Example: First thing I needed to learn is how do I hide backfaces? So I check the manual on blender.org

It says to uncheck 2 sided, it is located in the game setting. I have no such thing or can't locate any game setting.

In fact the whole manual I am suppose to know where everything is, nowhere is stated where anything is located. That is the biggest problem I keep having with Blender is knowing where anything is.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Blender has advanced much over the years, but the documentation has unfortunately not kept up as fast. Unlike commercial software companies, there is no paid staff to update the manual, so it's mostly done at a volunteer level... (maybe you'll even want to lend a hand at some point!). There are other resources however, like this website. If you ask specific questions we'll be glad to help you out. Also, please take a look at the resources put together on this page, maybe they will help you get started: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: As for this site, use the search function on the top righ of the page to get results like: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3712/hide-backface-with-xray-and-object-wire-mode , and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/how-can-i-stop-blender-from-selecting-vertices-on-backfaces/22983#22983 , and: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/how-can-i-stop-blender-from-selecting-vertices-on-backfaces/43925#43925

Comment: Coming from Max I learned Blender's interface mainly by watching [Andrew Price's videos](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCOKHwx1VCdgnxwbjyb9Iu1g) and following along.  After a little while you get used to where most of the usual stuff is, then you just pick up more stuff along the way from sites like this.

Comment: It said on this page "1 answer" now it doesn't say how many answers here anymore. I commented on one answer and don't see that answer or my reply. Now more bafled than ever.

Comment: When I go to shading I get this:
[link]http://s29.postimg.org/du0ih2hdz/culling.jpg[link]
This does not match any graphics on any search i did  for how to find backface culling in Blender.

Comment: Back faces are culled by default, they'll show in the 3d view, but when you render it out it won't show the back faces

Comment: The question is about the manual... **to ask a question about backface culling please make another post**. Please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @EricHuelin we are allowed to delete answers, I didn't think mine helped you so I extracted myself from this question.